# Spark View Engine: How to set default master page name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, master-pages, spark-view-engine

I use Spark View Engine with nested master pages. I have Application.spark which defines the basic layout of the website. Then there are several other masters which themselves use Application.spark as master page (Default.spark, SinlgeColumn.spark, Gallery.spark, ...)

If no master page is specified in a view file, then automatically Application.spark is choosen by the Spark View Engine. Since almost all my pages use "Default.spark" as master, is there a way to configure this globally?

The other possibilities would be:

1. Set the master in each spark file individually `<use master="Default" />`. But that's really annoying.
2. Rename my master files (Default.spark <-> Application.spark) but that really doesn't make any sense in naming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your issue:

1. Less work - but more repetitive.
2. More work, but drives out your preferred convention.

## Less Work

With any `ActionResult`, you can simply add a second parameter to the return statement to specify the name of the master to use:

```
return View("Gallery", "Default");
```

the first parameter name is the view and the second signifies a master page override...but that does mean you need to repeat it everywhere, and this isn't much better than what you had before.

## More Work

The way that Spark locates the master page to use is via the following code in the framework:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<string> PotentialDefaultMasterLocations(string controllerName, IDictionary<string, object> extra)
    {
        return ApplyFilters(new[]
                                {
                                    "Layouts\\" + controllerName + ".spark",
                                    "Shared\\" + controllerName + ".spark",
                                    "Layouts\\Application.spark",
                                    "Shared\\Application.spark"
                                }, extra);
    }
```

Notice the *hardcoded* `Application.spark` in there - that's a Spark convention. What it seems that you want to do is override this method and put something like this in instead:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<string> PotentialDefaultMasterLocations(string controllerName, IDictionary<string, object> extra)
    {
        return ApplyFilters(new[]
                                {
                                    "Layouts\\" + controllerName + ".spark",
                                    "Shared\\" + controllerName + ".spark",
                                    "Layouts\\Default.spark",
                                    "Shared\\Default.spark"
                                    "Layouts\\Application.spark",
                                    "Shared\\Application.spark"
                                }, extra);
    }
```

Then it will find your `Default.spark` before it finds `Application.spark` or you could get rid of the `Application.spark` entirely if it doesn't ring true for you and you prefer your conventions...

In order to override this, all you need to do is create a class that inherits from `Spark.Web.Mvc.DefaultDescriptorBuilder` and override that method mentioned above and use it when you register the view engine like so:

```
public static void RegisterViewEngine(ICollection<IViewEngine> engines)
{
    var services = SparkEngineStarter.CreateContainer();
    services.SetServiceBuilder<IDescriptorBuilder>(
        c => new MyDescriptorBuilder());
    SparkEngineStarter.RegisterViewEngine(services);
}
```

This now means that you can now direct where Spark should look for the Master views and what the names will be.

Hope that helps,
All the best,
RobertTheGrey

Comment: The "More Work" approach can also be used for creating a "themeable" system (CMS, Blog, etc).

Comment: Thanks Robert, this is great! I think the "Less Work" approach is even worse than setting the master in each view, so I went with the "More work". That's a really clean (and extensible) solution.

Comment: I couldn't agree more - I actually couldn't even remember how to do the "Less Work" option - had to look it up ;-). I'm not a fan of any magic strings running around the code if I can help it, but it's there for compatibility with native WebForms, so whatcha gonna do? Glad you picked the second option, it's actually less work in the long run ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it works, but try adding

```
<use master="Default" />
```

in a file called `Views\_global.spark`. It's automatically included in all views.

I usally add namespaces and global vars to my `_global.spark`.

Example:

```
<use namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>

<global type="string" Title="'My default title'"/>
```

### Another cool feature

Since you are a new spark user I would like to show you another cool spark feature.

Instead of writing

```
Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.FirstName);
```

you can write

```
<Label For="FirstName" />
```

Makes the views a bit cleaner, huh? The magic is done with something called bindings. All you need to do is to create a `Views\Bindings.xml` file and add bindings to it.

Read more in this blog entry: http://blog.robertgreyling.com/2010/08/spark-bindings-are-you-tired-of-eating.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding `<use master="Default" />` to `_global.spark` unforunately didn't work - I tried that before. Yeah, I know some of the other cool features that Spark has, I'm not that new to it. And besides the clean syntax, these little extras are the reason I love Spark! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Application.spark as your base, and Default.spark as your 2nd level...
rename Default.spark to Application.spark and the application.spark to something else like BaseApplication.spark.

This way, by default your application.spark is picked up, but if you wish to override it you can referece the BaseApplication.spark.

See the three pass rendering section for an example.
http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/master-layouts#Threepassrendering